# Having difficulties with php foreach and passing by reference

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm pulling some data from a database (with a function I have called query), and I want to add another key/value pair to each result, i.e.:

```
$items = query("SELECT * FROM items");

foreach($items as &$item) {
    $item['fixedname'] = str_replace(' ','_',$item['name']);
}
```

Now I want to put these on an html view, i.e.:

```
<?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
<div id="<?= $item['fixedname'] ?>" ><?= $item['name'] ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

However, this doesn't output correctly. For instance, when the query returns two items, the loop in the php outputs the same thing twice. If there are three: it outputs the first one, then two of the second one. What's the problem here?

Comment: what is the reason for using reference here?

Comment: What @Akam said. Don't use reference with PHP unless you are absolutely sure of what you are doing. Use copy instead.

Comment: I need to add a new key into the array (fixedname) that was in it before. Without passing the reference, it wasn't being added in outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data returned on the right side of the foreach is a copy of the data, it can't be modified directly.  Instead you need to fetch both the $key (the ID of the item in the array) and the $item.  By letting PHP telling you the $key you don't need to worry about whether the array is normal (e.g. having indexes of 0,1,2,...) and associative.

```
This example would walk the $items array and add 'fixedname' into it.

foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    $items[$key]['fixedname'] = str_replace(' ','_',$item['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When modifying using foreach() I've had weird results on occasion.  I use

```
foreach ($items as $key=>$value) {
    $items[$key] = modified($value);
}
```

Or, why not do it in the SQL `SELECT your, fields, here, REPLACE(name, ' ', '-') AS fixedname`

Comment: What if I need to add in another key/value pair outright, which will be given another value through php later? Is there any way to do that, or if not, create an empty return value with the SQL statement?

Comment: You can create "dummy" fields in your SQL - `SELECT field1, field2, TRIM('') AS field3` for instance - but I'd not recommend it. If you keep going down the route of adding more & more dummies like that then I'd suggest rethinking your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a normal for loop

```
<?php 
    for($i=0; $i < count($items); $i++){
        $items[$i]['fixedname'] = str_replace(' ','_',$items[$i]['name']);
    }
?>
```

Then everything will be ready when you go to your next foreach.

Comment: This works. I still don't know what was happening in the first case, though.

Answer (score 0):

u have bunch of wrong things

**1**- dont use mysql , use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead

**2**- `$items = query("SELECT *  ....` --->Call to undefined function query()

change it to

```
$items = mysql_query("SELECT *  ....
```

**3**-  `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` ,

you missed to fetch your query

try this whole code

```
 $items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items");

 ?>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($items) ) {?>
 <div id="<?php echo $row['fixedname'] ;?>" ><?php echo $row['name']; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Danthier stated he had a method called `query` which presumably returns a list of items.